# Debugging two spring web services in vscode fails

Tags: spring, spring-boot, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I have created two simple Spring Boot web services in vscode, and one of the web services calls the other so I need to run them both at the same time while debugging at least one of them. Both of them work if I debug them independently, for example if I just right click the main class and select the Debug command from the menu. For example, I do this sequence:

1. Start Service1 in Debug
2. Test Service1 by making a call to the URL from the browser and verify it works (it does)
3. Start Service2 in Debug
4. Check to see that Service2 is running (it is)
5. Try to test Service2 by making a call to its URL from the browser. It crashes (disappears from running processes)
6. Stop all debugging
7. Start Service2 in Debug
8. Start Service1 in Debug
9. Try to test Service1 by making a call to its URL from the browser. It crashes.

I've added the two services as compounds in launch.json but that didn't help. The first service that starts works while the second one crashes.

Does anyone have any recommended configuration settings that I should check?

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that I had both services listening on the same port.